# How Do I Program this Timer Switch

Tags: switch, timer, light

There is a timer switch in my garage which I can't figure out how to properly use.  What I know about it:

- It controls my driveway lights
- There are time tick marks around the circumference of the dial, and it rotates.
- The dial is also a button (you can push it)
- When it is switched to the ON position, the only way I can turn the lights on/off is to push in the dial.  Once I do that, the lights seem to stay on 24 hrs/day.  Pushing the dial button again is the only way I can turn the lights off.
- There is an LED behind the small window above the OFF/ON switch.  It starts flashing when I switch from OFF to ON, and eventually becomes solid (non-flashing).

My objective is to program the driveway lights to turn on/off at specific times, but can't figure it out.  Does anyone know the logo in the center of the dial?  Maybe I can try finding instructions on the internet.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: The proper way to have responded to your own question was to post an answer to it. You can still do that if you want to clean things up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED ON MY OWN

In case this can help anyone else, the logo is Intermatic and I found the instructions for this model here:

http://www.intermatic.com/-/media/inriver/6842-8228.ashx/EJ351-Instructions-EN

Comment: Mind putting a summary of how to program it here in case the link breaks?